# NSFetchedResultsController conflict with number of changed records

Tags: ios, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have an iPad app with ARC, storyboards, supporting ios5+.

I have a VC that is working with NSFetchedResultsController on its own.
The VC has two tableviews pointing at two different entities.
I have single record add, change, delete, and moving of rows working fine on this VC.

I've now introduced a new feature to enable the user to quick add multiple rows to these tableviews.
I do this by providing a segue (modal) from this VC to a new VC (lets call it quickAddVC).
The user enters the data on quickAddVC, and then I segue back (modal) to the original VC.
I save the new records (via an alternate call) before (I believe) setting up the NSFetchedResultsControllers for the VC again (I set them to nil in ViewDidUnload).

However I keep getting this mismatch error.
Somehow it keeps registering the number of inserts that occur from the quickAddVC as 1 insert no matter how many records I add, and it somehow remembers how many records were in the NSFetchedResultsControllers before my segues to do this comparison.

Error:

> *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /SourceCache/UIKit/UIKit-2372/UITableView.m:1070
>
> Failure in didChangeObject, name=NSInternalInconsistencyException reason=Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (5) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (2), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (1 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong or should try would be useful.

I can't figure out how to get the NSFetchedResultsControllers to simply forget its original state and restart from scratch which would I think resolve this issue for me.

I haven't posted any of the code, I guess I could post a lot if needed but hoping there is enough here to outline the design issue and get some ideas.

Comment: Ok solved the issue.

Basically I was clearing the NSFetchedResultsControllers in the wrong place.
By setting them to nil just prior to the segue all works fine.

I'd made an incorrect assumption that given the ViewDidLoad method was being called when I segued back again, that the ViewDidUnload method was also being called but that was not the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just reposting the answer to mark question as closed.

Ok solved the issue. Basically I was clearing the NSFetchedResultsControllers in the wrong place. By setting them to nil just prior to the segue all works fine. I'd made an incorrect assumption that given the ViewDidLoad method was being called when I segued back again, that the ViewDidUnload method was also being called but that was not the case.